# Postgresql: invalid record length at 29/E4624520 but replication looks fine

Tags: postgresql, replication, write-ahead-logging

What is this error? I see that replication is working fine, but I am not so sure if the data is being corrupted or not.

Can I safely ignore this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cannot do anything else than quoting [an entry from the pgsql-admin mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAHGQGwFvv0pxaf_iZ1FU1H%3Dd%3DexhPUoM0ss-9GkDWRP%3DFureMg%40mail.gmail.com):

> Just after startup, the standby tries to read and replay the WAL files
>   which exist in the standby, and then if it finds invalid WAL record,
>   IOW, it can no longer read valid WAL record locally, it starts
>   replication and tries to read the WAL files from the master. So the
>   above log message "invalid  record ..." means that there is no valid
>   WAL record in the standby, which triggers the replication. Since valid
>   WAL records are streamed from the master, you don't need to worry
>   about that log message.

It's worth noting that that line is only a `LOG` level message.

Comment: +1 for you. I see this quote before, but it is repeating in every forum, because that i am asking here again to check if that is right.